# I need to move LVM PEs to a smaller disk, will this work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, migration

I need to migrate Ubuntu to a smaller disk.

I have a VM with the first disk that is 50GiB :

```bash
$ sudo parted /dev/sda unit mib print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 51200MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start    End       Size      File system  Name                 Flags
        0.02MiB   1.00MiB   0.98MiB   Free Space
 1      1.00MiB   2.00MiB   1.00MiB                BIOS boot partition  bios_grub
        2.00MiB   2050MiB   2048MiB   Free Space
 2      2050MiB   51199MiB  49149MiB               LVM VG_SYSTEM        lvm
        51199MiB  51200MiB  0.98MiB   Free Space
```

It contains one VG of 48GiB-1MiB that has only 25GiB-1MiB occupied :

```bash
$ sudo pvs -o +pv_used --units m
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize     PFree     Used
  /dev/sda2  VG_SYSTEM lvm2 a--  49148.00m 23552.00m 25596.00m
```

If I add a new 25GiB disk with a BIOS boot partition of 1MiB and another partition of 25GiB-1MiB and do a `sudo pvmove /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2` will this work ?

Comment: Do not add the answer in the question. Add it below.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

I added a new 25GiB disk and re-scanned the scsi hosts. Then I created a BIOS boot partition of 1MiB and another partition of 25GiB-1MiB :

```bash
$ echo "- - -" | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan >/dev/null
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit gi print
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label

Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 25.0GiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 
$ sudo parted -s /dev/sdb mktable gpt
$ sudo parted -s /dev/sdb mkpart '"BIOS boot partition"' 1Mi 4095s
$ sudo parted -s /dev/sdb set 1 bios_grub on
$ sudo parted -s /dev/sdb -- mkpart '"LVM VG_SYSTEM"' 2Mi -1s
$ sudo parted -s /dev/sdb set 2 lvm on
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit mib print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 25600MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start    End       Size      File system  Name                 Flags
        0.02MiB  1.00MiB   0.98MiB   Free Space
 1      1.00MiB  2.00MiB   1.00MiB                BIOS boot partition  bios_grub
 2      2.00MiB  25600MiB  25598MiB               LVM VG_SYSTEM        lvm
```

Then I created a LVM PV on /dev/sda2 added it to the VG_SYSTEM VG and moved the PEs :

```bash
$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb2
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb2" successfully created.
$ sudo vgextend VG_SYSTEM /dev/sdb2
  Volume group "VG_SYSTEM" successfully extended
$ time sudo pvmove /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 0.06%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 7.97%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 17.25%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 22.61%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 29.66%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 39.96%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 47.79%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 55.81%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 61.51%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 63.99%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 74.78%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 80.00%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 86.26%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 94.22%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 96.00%
  /dev/sda2: Moved: 100.00%

real    4m0.447s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.009s
```

And finally I removed /dev/sdb2 from the VG_SYSTEM VG :

```bash
$ sudo vgreduce VG_SYSTEM /dev/sda2
  Removed "/dev/sda2" from volume group "VG_SYSTEM"
$ sudo pvremove /dev/sda2
  Labels on physical volume "/dev/sda2" successfully wiped.
$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb2  VG_SYSTEM lvm2 a--  <25.00g    0
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
$
```

It worked like a charm :-)